# glassfish 3.1 b41 sslv3 disable

Tags: ssl, glassfish

For some security issue, I should disable glassfish's iiop's port ssl3

I have tried many times as the Oracle's guidance, but all failed.

Firstly, I used the admin console, run the command like this:

```
sh asadmin -H localhsot - p adminport
set server.iiop-service.iiop-listener.SSL.ssl.ssl3-enabled=false
```

the console show Command set executed successfully. Then I restart the server to effect the modification.

Lastly, I run the `openssl` command to verify modification, but it still can handshake via sslv3.

```
[root@SHCLITVM0124 /]# openssl s_client -connect locahost:10005 -ssl3
```

I have tried another way to disable SSLV3: go to the web admin portal, uncheck the checkbox of SSLV3 as the below picture, then restart the server, rerun the command `openssl` to verify this port's ssl3, but the result is not as what I expected.

[image: screenshot-1]

[image: screenshot-2]

I a new to `glassfish`, and have no clue about what is wrong here.